# Code works in Debug mode but when I run the code there is "type mismatch" error.

Tags: type-mismatch

One of the used references for my code is Refprop which includes required functions such as Temperature. In debug mode, there isn't any problem, but when outside the vb I run the code there is a "type mismatch" error to calculate TR_O_P_Com.

Option Explicit

Sub Simulation()

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate: Range("A:ZZ").Select: Selection.ClearContents
'

TR_O_P_Com = Temperature("R134A", "HP", "si", HR_O_P_Com / 1000, PR_S_P_C) - 273.15

and when I use F8 in debug mode there isn't any problem! I have declared all of the variables such as HR_O_P_Com and TR_O_P_Com.

I am so grateful if you help me to remove this error.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Seems like dll and exe has different method signature. For example in dll method A(int a, int b) and in exe you are calling with A(int a, char c). But not sure. Use all the latest dll and exe after the compilation and try again.

Did you compile the code in release mode? First use the exe that has been generated in debug mode out side of vb. If that works fine then try with the exe in release mode.

Comment: Thanks Abhijit,
I use add-in in excel for some calculation. I am trying to have all the calculation in the VBA and just use excel as the main output screen and also to run the excelsolver. 


In the main calculation, the refprop add-in has been introduced for excel and also for VB the same add-in is as the reference. I disabled the add-in in excel but still I have the type miss-match error.

  
Subrotine works in vb using F5 or when I debug using F8 but when I want to run the subrotine in excel and click the assigned button there is type miss-match error.